# onclick div id used for file name

Tags: jquery

I'd like to take the id of a div and use it to call a file name but I'm not sure how to do it.

For example the element is

```
<p id="smith_janis" class="name">Janis Smith</p>
```

and so something like

```
$(".name").click(function() {
  $(this).get the element's id and turn it into variale maybe?

  $("#text").load(the name of the element +".txt"); or $("#text").load("smith_janis.txt");

});
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this, can someone help me out?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, you would use something like this:

```
$(".name").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#text").load(id +".txt");
});
```

Comment: so if you had several elements with the name class would the variable update each time a different one was clicked?

Comment: Yes, thats the nice things about attaching event handlers to a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()`

```
$(".name").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id') ;  $(this) is a -- jQuery Object 
             **OR**
    var id = this.id ;   this is a -- DOM Object 
    $("#text").load(id + '.txt');

});
```

Comment: i feel dumb asking this, but what's the difference btw a jQuery object and a DOM Object?

Comment: jQuery Object is a DOM element wrapped using the jQuery Wrapper

Comment: Just stick to your original answer, or add the comments back in.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Hint:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```